# Store data from array to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

There is an array gGroupArray of type structure GroupType

```
 Public Structure GroupType
    Dim bChecked As Boolean
    Dim iCategoryID As Short
    Dim tProductGroup As String
 End Structure

 Public gGroupArray() As GroupType
```

Data is stored in gGroupArray. There is data grid view named as GroupGrid

```
      With GroupGrid
        Dim objCB As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        With objCB
            .Name = "CB"
        End With
        .Columns.Add(objCB)

        Dim objProductGroup As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With objProductGroup
            .Name = "ProductGroup"
        End With
        .Columns.Add(objProductGroup)

        Dim objCategoryId As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With objCategoryId
            .Name = "CategoryID"
        End With
        .Columns.Add(objCategoryId)
    End With
    GroupGrid.RowCount = UBound(gGroupArray)
    GroupGrid.Rows.Add(GroupGrid.RowCount)
```

I have to store the gGroupArray data into GroupGrid. How this can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create **three** columns, then use this code:

```
Public Sub Load_Items(ByRef Array() As GroupType, ByRef DataGrid As DataGridView)
    For Each Item As GroupType In Array
        With Item
            DataGrid.Rows.Add(.bChecked, .iCategoryID, .tProductGroup)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

the first parameter is **gGroupArray** and the second is your **DataGridView name**.

Tell me if it works! :)

Comment: The OP seems to have problems to understand how to instantiate an array and, presumably, will not find your answer too useful. I was writing an answer myself but if you could address this issue I will delete it.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too!, btw, I will wait his reply and so we can determine if he really want to  load from a array, you can post an answer anyway :)

Comment: I waited for a while but you didn't answer and that's why I wrote mine. "If he really want to load from a array"?! It has to: otherwise how would your code work? what is "Array() As GroupType" other than an array?! LOL. If you update your answer and reflect this issue (tell the OP how to populate the array/dimension it) I would delete mine.

Comment: also please remove the DataGrid.Rows.Clear() part. What is the point? How you know that the OP wants to delete all the previous rows with each new insertion?

Comment: I gave him temporary answer and I answered him just what he's looking for. I know it was an array but i'm not sure what he's looking for, that's what i mean

Comment: I am not insinuating that... but when a person does not understand something properly, it seems better to rely on things he can easily relate to for the explanations. One thing is a highly-knowledgeable OP asking a specific issue and a different thing is someone posting a code which shows clear lacks of knowledge (from his code is pretty clear that he does not know how to deal with arrays properly). I mean... this is how I think. Perhaps the OP prefers your option, let's see.

Comment: PS: I didn't mean you to change the name of the variables, but to explain how to instatiate Array() (because if he uses your function with its current gGroupArray() it will logically trigger an error).

Comment: PPS: also still not sure about the point of DataGrid.Rows.Clear() and not explaining this issue. Also it is a bit confusing the fact that you take the DataGridView as an argument but rely on a sub (don't return the modified version); if you rely on a globally defined variable (what is actually what the OP's code does), what is the point of including the DataGridView as argument? As you can see... I can see various things wrong/unclear in your answer but everything would be acceptable if the array-instantiation issue would have been cleared out.

Comment: i can't see a "clear lacks of knowledge" from his code, coz of course he's not posting his full code and maybe he knows everything about arrays but he don't wanna post everything.

Comment: if u see it unclear then let me clarify, i included the DataGridView in the params coz what if there're 2 data grids. of cource i won't write the same code twice, it's just very logical that loading has source and destination

Comment: I don't think that the "clear lacks of knowledge" statement is bad; it is what this code reflects. Bear in mind that his code is being called from the Form Load event and thus this is the first code being executed (and the array is used without being instantiated -> wrong). Even by forgetting that, this code transmits that the OP does not know to deal with arrays and he is here to learn and get help; his code transmits that he needs some help on this front if this is not the case, there is no problem: over-helping is never a problem.

Comment: he didn't say that "this code" is from the **load**. it's just to describe his data grid columns looks like

Comment: Regarding your last statement OK; I would rely on a function in this case but is OK. The reason why I highlighted that too is that you are writing a code with so many "new things", some of these things not clear (at least to me) and you are not explaining anything, just saying: take that and see if it works. This was the point of my comments.

Comment: Ah... sorry you are right (there is no reference to the form load event, THIS TIME). I answered yesterday another question to this OP and that's why I said that (I play with some advantage on knowing this code :)).

Comment: Actually... the whole point of my assumption was that (assuming that was the form load event). Hmm... perhaps the OP is populating/instantiating the array properly! This is a solid enough reason to delete my answer; but, please, consider what I have said you mainly on the rows.clear front (and on explaining things).

Comment: thanks for being critic! i like that coz yesterday i created my account and im pretty new here. so excuse me coz im still learning from what u said, i expected he will reply me what happened with him and i'll help him though comments. btw i removed the line that teases you LOL, i intentionally made my code as simple as he want

Comment: + don't delete your answer, maybe he really don't know how to work with arrays!

Comment: The whole point of this site is being critic and creating proper things: if you can do a proper thing completely by your own, you are welcome; if others can complement it, better. Feel free to correct me or any other asker/answerer... I deleted my answer because you answered before and my answer didn't include any valuable over-information; I thought that the arrays bit was relevant but you are right, in the post there is no mention of that; so... what is the point? If the OP tells you that there is an error, just make sure that he is instantiating/populating the array properly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and enjoy the site; I am a bit more experienced than you although not too much (a bit more than 3 months old); but anyone is here to help, so better learning/growing with this help.

Comment: okay :) thanks for ur time.
ps. just undelete your comment, he will like reading 2 answers instead of 1 ^_^

Comment: ?! Don't worry he has information more than enough. Additionally, I don't want to participate in "all-say-the-same-thing" contests; if I consider that can provide something objectively valuable to the OP (& future readers) I would write an answer, otherwise not. I might correct various issues from yours, but are secondary issues: for example using .Rows.Add(.bChecked, .iCategoryID, .tProductGroup) instead of creating a new object. But this is low-valuable information.  I am here to help, if someone has already done that why I would write anything (eventually correct via comments nothing else)?

Comment: i would like to write the add method as u described, but if the OP looked at **add** overloads he won't see something that accept 3 parameters and i don't know if he will understand that the ,,, means an object array!
do u suggest me to update the code to ur form. or just keep it with this **beginner** form

Comment: As said, is a low-importance issue, but works perfectly. They are not 3 parameters, but the object you are referring, provided in a different way (more appealing way; because the target method allows it). I mentioned that as one of the slight "corrections" I might include to your answer (once you removed the rows.Clear) and that's why I preferred to delete it. You are free to add this alternative to your code, don't worry I don't own the copyright :)

Comment: LOL it's open source time yay :D
i'll update to your code as long as the OP seems to be in love with the **with** statment LOL

Comment: OK. Happy to be of help :)